# Помогите исправить ошибку в задании

Tags: java

Помогите с данной ошибкой пожалуйста.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at lab.DoubleArray.addPoint(DoubleArray.java:38)
        at lab.AbstractArrayOfPoints.test(AbstractArrayOfPoints.java:45)
        at lab.DoubleArray.main(DoubleArray.java:55)
    C:\Users\apolo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
    СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

## AbstractArrayOfPoints.class

```
    public abstract class AbstractArrayOfPoints {

    public abstract void setPoint(int i, double x, double y);

    public abstract double getX(int i);

    public abstract double getY(int i);

    public abstract int count();

    public abstract void addPoint(double x, double y);

    public abstract void removeLast();

    public void sortByX() {
        boolean mustSort; 

        do {
            mustSort = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < count() - 1; i++) {
                if (getX(i) > getX(i + 1)) {
                    double x = getX(i);
                    double y = getY(i);
                    setPoint(i, getX(i + 1), getY(i + 1));
                    setPoint(i + 1, x, y);
                    mustSort = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (mustSort);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count(); i++) {
            s += "x = " + getX(i) + " \ty = " + getY(i) + "\n";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }

    public void test() {
        addPoint(22, 45);
        addPoint(4, 11);
        addPoint(30, 5.5);
        addPoint(-2, 48);
        sortByX();
        System.out.println(this);
    }

}
```

## DoubleArray.class

```
public class DoubleArray extends AbstractArrayOfPoints{

    private double[][] array = {{ },{ }};

    @Override
    public void setPoint(int i, double x, double y) {
        if(i < count()){
            array[i][i] = x;
            array[i][i+1] = y;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double getX(int i) {
        return array[i][i];
    }

    @Override
    public double getY(int i) {
        return array[i][i+1];
    }

    @Override
    public int count() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
        double[][] axy = new double[array.length + 1][array.length];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, axy, 0, array.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < axy.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < axy[i].length; j++){
                axy[i][j] = x;
                axy[i][j+1] = y;
            }
        }
        array = axy;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeLast() {
        if (count() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        double[][] axy = new double[array.length - 1][array.length - 2];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, axy, 0, axy.length);
        array = axy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DoubleArray().test();
    }
}
```

## UPD.

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at lab.DoubleArray.getX(DoubleArray.java:17)
    at lab.AbstractArrayOfPoints.sortByX(AbstractArrayOfPoints.java:23)
    at lab.AbstractArrayOfPoints.test(AbstractArrayOfPoints.java:49)
    at lab.DoubleArray.main(DoubleArray.java:54)
C:\Users\apolo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

## AbstractArrayOfPoints.class

```
package lab;

public abstract class AbstractArrayOfPoints {

    public abstract void setPoint(int i, double x, double y);

    public abstract double getX(int i);

    public abstract double getY(int i);

    public abstract int count();

    public abstract void addPoint(double x, double y);

    public abstract void removeLast();

    public void sortByX() {
        boolean mustSort; 

        do {
            mustSort = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < count() - 1; i++) {
                if (getX(i) > getX(i + 1)) {
                    double x = getX(i);
                    double y = getY(i);
                    setPoint(i, getX(i + 1), getY(i + 1));
                    setPoint(i + 1, x, y);
                    mustSort = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (mustSort);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count(); i++) {
            s += "x = " + getX(i) + " \ty = " + getY(i) + "\n";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }

    public void test() {
        addPoint(22, 45);
        addPoint(4, 11);
        addPoint(30, 5.5);
        addPoint(-2, 48);
        sortByX();
        System.out.println(this);
        }
    }
```

## DoubleArray.class

```
package lab;

public class DoubleArray extends AbstractArrayOfPoints {

    private double[][] array = {{}, {}};

    @Override
    public void setPoint(int i, double x, double y) {
        if (i < count()) {
            array[i][0] = x;
            array[i][1] = y;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double getX(int i) {
        return array[i][0];
    }

    @Override
    public double getY(int i) {
        return array[i][1];
    }

    @Override
    public int count() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
        final int len = array.length;

        double[][] axy = new double[len + 1][len];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, axy, 0, len);

        axy[len][0] = x;
        axy[len][1] = y;

        array = axy;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeLast() {
        if (count() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        double[][] axy = new double[array.length - 1][array.length];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, axy, 0, axy.length);
        array = axy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DoubleArray().test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка выхода за пределы массива, скорее всего тут: `axy[i][j+1] = y;`, в этой строчке `lab.DoubleArray.addPoint(DoubleArray.java:38)` указано что в таком то методе, такой-то файл, такая-то строка ошибка. Кст, а 38 строке у вас что находится?

Comment: @gil9red В 38-й строке находится вот этот кусок кода: `axy[i][j+1] = y;`

Comment: Ну, значит я был прав :) Проблема, думаю в `j+1`. У вас размер массива в `axy[i]` -- 2 элемента, наверное это для двух точек: x и y. А `j+1` обращается к 3-й элементу, которого нет

Comment: @gil9red Если так переписать та же самая ошибка будет:
`@Override
    public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
        double[][] axy = new double[array.length + 1][array.length + 2];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, axy, 0, array.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < axy.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < axy[i].length; j++){
                axy[i][j] = x;
                axy[i][j + 1] = y;
            }
        }
        array = axy;
    }`

Comment: Добавил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: компилятор написал, что ошибка в функции сортировки, и что она вызвана выходом за границы массива. Он даже написал номер строки. Ошибка тут:  `for (int i = 0; i < count() - 1; i++) {  if (getX(i) > getX(i + 1))`. Думаю, что ты сам сможешь ее найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, реализация `addPoint` должна была быть такой:

```
@Override
public void addPoint(double x, double y) {
    final int len = array.length;

    double[][] axy = new double[len + 1][len];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, axy, 0, len);

    axy[len][0] = x;
    axy[len][1] = y;

    array = axy;
}
```

**UPD.**

Заметил, что похожая ошибка работы с `x` и `y` есть и в других метода:

```
@Override
public double getX(int i) {
    return array[i][0];
}

@Override
public double getY(int i) {
    return array[i][1];
}
```

---

PS. а почему бы вместо массивов не использовать `ArrayList`?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at lab.DoubleArray.getX(DoubleArray.java:17)
at lab.AbstractArrayOfPoints.sortByX(AbstractArrayOfPoints.java:23)
 at lab.AbstractArrayOfPoints.test(AbstractArrayOfPoints.java:49)
at lab.DoubleArray.main(DoubleArray.java:54)
C:\Users\apolo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 0 секунд)`

Comment: @ЖеняРыбалко, ошибка в другом месте: `lab.DoubleArray.getX(DoubleArray.java:17)`, а значит не в моей функции. Видите по стеку, что сначала код зашел в test, потом в sortByX, после в getX и там упал? А по коду, у вас sortByX вызывается после addPoint, а значит, то что я в ответе написал сработало без ошибки

Comment: По заданию сказано двухмерный массив использовать, поэтому не `ArrayList`.

Comment: @ЖеняРыбалко, добавил в ответ как исправить такую ошибку с пояснением. Если у вас есть такие же ошибки (я не смотрел весь код), сами исправьте :)

Comment: Вроде все поправил по такому же принципу, но не работает. Внес изменения в вопрос

Comment: Может еще сможете, что подсказать :)

Comment: @ЖеняРыбалко, `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` значит у массива длина 0, т.е. в нем ничего нет, и соответственно, обращение к первому элементу (индекс 0) вызывает ошибку. Если мой ответ с проблемой в вопросе примите его. Если есть и другие вопросы / проблемы, то имеет смысл не править вопрос, делая неправильным мой ответ, а создавать новые вопросы по новым проблемам :)

Comment: Спасибо. Уже разобрался в данной ошибке :)

Comment: Молодец, что смогли разобраться :)